# Subscribing tags not working

Tags: bug, tags, email

I am trying to subscribe to few tags on Stack Overflow and I get error - "no email address set -- please enter one in your profile".

Seems obvious error, other than that

- I already have email in my profile in Stack Overflow under - https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/[num]
- copied over my email under StackExchange network as well under - https://stackexchange.com/users/7637830/calvintada
  and I still get the same error.

Do I need to update it anywhere else?

Comment: What do you mean by "subscribe to tags"? You mean adding them to your favorite tag list?

Comment: I go to "Tags" under stackoverflow.com - hover on any tag and there is a "subscribe" link.  I am interested in few topics and want to be notified when there is a question asked with this tag. Thats the idea. If there is a better way to do this, pls advice.

Comment: Ah okay, I've never even noticed that link! It seems to work for me. Just to be sure, does the "your communities" section at the top of the email settings page include Stack Overflow?

Comment: Stackoverflow > Edit Profile & Settings > Site settings > Hide communities link I an sss stack overflow under "Visibile communities" section. There is no "your communities " section anywhere...

Comment: I have exactly the same issue on other StackExchange sites for several weeks. Specifically, I'm unable to subscribe to a tag at https://physics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Possibly relevant: the *My Logins* section of my profile contains 2 email addresses. When I subscribe to a tag, I'm sent a confirmation email to an address which *isn't* either of those listed on my profile settings - it's an email address I wasn't aware SO had for my account, and it's not an address I actively use to log in with, either.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. Is anyone from StackExchange listening?

Comment: Make sure you've set an email at: https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/9114542 @CalvinTada

Comment: Yes, it is setup and have saved once more. Still same error / behaviour.

Comment: Ok.. Will assume that this is a bug (or) may be something is wrong with my profile. How do I file the bug report ?

Comment: @CalvinTada, [the recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188266/how-do-i-report-a-bug-related-to-stack-exchange) is to tag the question at StackExchange with [meta-tag:bug]. I do not know if that applies to StackOverflow.

Comment: I started getting tag subscribe mails, but with more than 1 day delay from question entered